# How to center text from cell_spec() in kableExtra using CSS?

Tags: css, r, kableextra

I was kindly provided a workaround using the `extra_css =` argument in `cell_spec()` from the `kableExtra` package that enables me to fill the entire cell of the table rather than just the text. However, despite setting `align = c("l", "c")` in the `kbl()` call, the output results in the text in the `val` column not centering.

I'm really hoping to get the text centre aligned for an R Markdown report, so if anyone can suggest a workaround for this, perhaps using CSS, that will be great! Thanks.

```
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(123)

name <- paste("Name", LETTERS)
val <- rnorm(26, 100, 50)
d <- data.frame(name, val)

d$val <- cell_spec(d$val,
                   background = dplyr::case_when(
                     d$val > mean(d$val) + sd(d$val) ~ "#DBEBF6",
                     d$val < mean(d$val) - sd(d$val) ~ "#FEE7DA",
                     .default = "transparent"
                   ),
                   extra_css = "margin: -8px; padding: 8px; display: flex;",
                   background_as_tile = FALSE
)

kbl(d, escape = FALSE, align = c("l", "c")) %>%
  kable_styling()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(kableExtra)

set.seed(123)

name <- paste("Name", LETTERS)
val <- rnorm(26, 100, 50)
d <- data.frame(name, val)

d$val <- cell_spec(d$val,
                   background = dplyr::case_when(
                     d$val > mean(d$val) + sd(d$val) ~ "#DBEBF6",
                     d$val < mean(d$val) - sd(d$val) ~ "#FEE7DA",
                     .default = "white"
                   ),
                   extra_css = "margin: -8px; padding: 8px; display: flex;",
                   background_as_tile = FALSE
)

kbl(d, escape = FALSE, align = c("l", "c")) %>%
  kable_styling(full_width = F)
```

For HTML output you can achieve this by turning off `full_width` within `kable_styling()`.

Helpful stuff on that here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html

Comment: Thanks, @RKeithL. The column header of `val` is centered with my code, but not the rows/values within that column. I'd like these centered which my code does not produce.

Comment: Honestly trying to help, @Ben_89, but the image I posted *does* appear to show both a centered heading as well as centered values for the `val` column. I should add that the image I posted is from R markdown to PDF.

Comment: I appreciate it, @RKeithL! Perhaps the reason my code isn't centered is I'm trying to knit to an HTML document. Could that be a viable reason as to why I'm running into issues?

Comment: Updated answer. Cheers!

Comment: Just checking in, @Ben_89--did adjusting full_width work for you?

Comment: Sorry, @RKeithL. Had meant to reply sooner. Yes, it did work, thanks. I really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: Glad to hear it--cheers!